# How can I change order of arguments in vscode?

Tags: java

Example, I created a method like that:

```
void method(String a, int b){
    // do something
}
```

One day, how can I change order of argument like this if I had already use this method a lot in my project:

```
void method(int b, String a){
    // do something
}
```

My IDE is vscode

Comment: If this is a public API you don't. If this your own API, you change it everywhere you used the method. Is there some reason you've decided to do this? Whim can be painful.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload in java (have multiple methods with the same name, so long as they accept different parameters)

Comment: or u could use an or || and make a second statement after it

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really know that in vscode, but I think there is another workaround use function overload

```
void method(String a, int b){
    // do something
}

void method(int b, String a){
    method(a, b);
}
```